# Problems with paragraph spacing

Tags: formatting, paragraphs

I have been using the below control sequence to define a new paragraph that has no indentation:

```
\newcommand{\pgraph}{\paragraph\par\noindent\ignorespaces}
```

When I use this control sequence I get a closed square bracket in between the paragraphs like so:

[image]

I can get rid of this problem by adding `\mbox` to the control sequence. However this messes with the indentation of the paragraph by essentially adding a negative indentation for the first word.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  There's not enough of the example to debug the problem, but with most (all?) document classes, `\paragraph` takes an argument, and the way you're using it, `\par` is interpreted as the argument, which is surely not what you want.  If you provide a small, compilable example that results in the problem you see, someone here will be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: A new paragraph without indentation between  others indented paragraphs is just `\par\noindent`  and between no indented paragraphs is just `\par`, (of course with  `\parindent` set to `0pt` and `\parskip` set to more than  `0pt`  somewhere before, including the preamble). Moreover, instead of `\par` you can use simply a blank line, making text more readable for human eyes. Therefore, why the hell are you trying use a macro with the wrong commands instead of just use  `Enter`+`Enter`(or `Enter`+`Enter`+`\noindent`) ?

Comment: I would like a space inbetween paragraphs and leaving a blank line does not do this and neither does \par. However when I use \paragraph there is always an indentation even when I use \noindent

Answer (score 1):

```
\newcommand{\pgraph}{\paragraph\par\noindent\ignorespaces}
```

Despite its unfortunate name, `\paragraph` is unrelated to paragraphs of text, it is a section heading with the same syntax as `\section`

You have used `\paragraph\par` which will give the same error as `\section{\par}` with `\par` being the section heading:

```
Runaway argument?
{
! Paragraph ended before \@sect was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.5 \paragraph\par
                  
?
```

After any error the generated PDF is likely to be unusable and here, as you say, you get a `]` printed as latex can not recover from this error and some of the tokens designed to parse the optional argument to section headings get printed.

The actual use case appears to be to have pargraphs with no indent but vertical space between them, for which you can use the `parskip` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

Aaa aaa aaa. Aaa aaa aaa.Aaa aaa aaa.
Aaa aaa aaa. Aaa aaa aaa.Aaa aaa aaa.
Aaa aaa aaa. Aaa aaa aaa.Aaa aaa aaa.

Bbbb bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb .
Bbbb bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb .
Bbbb bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb  bbb bbb .
\end{document}
```